# How to program a task with a timer in my Python code?

Tags: python, timer, sleep, countdown

I want to execute a task after certain time, so I have tried a countdown timer with a condition of being finished (when countdown variable = 0, the task is performed). The thing is that I don't want to stop the execution of the main program while performing the countdown. I have tried this:

```
import time

def countdown(num_of_secs):
    while(num_of_secs):
        time.sleep(1)
        num_of_secs -= 1
        return num_of_secs
```

So, I run my code setting a number of seconds to the countdown, and when this countdown reaches the 0 value, a task must be executed. Using this code (it uses a while), when I call my function "countdown" it stops the execution of the main program, so it is the same as a big time.sleep. I want to carry out this countdown in the background, without stopping other actions until the countdown finishes and the task starts.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative is by using threading.
I've got a simple example here with 2 Threads where the working thread is waiting for the countdown thread to finish and starting. The Main is still working fine.

```
import threading
import time


def do_something():
    countdown_thread.join()
    print("Starting Task")
    time.sleep(3)
    print("Finished Task")

def countdown(num_of_secs):
    while(num_of_secs):
        time.sleep(1)
        num_of_secs -= 1
        print(num_of_secs)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    countdown_thread = threading.Thread(target=countdown, args=(3,))
    work_thread = threading.Thread(target=do_something)

    countdown_thread.start()
    work_thread.start()

    while True:
        print("Main doing something")
        time.sleep(1)
```

Example picture for multithreading: [Sequential vs Threading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuCBq.png)

Comment: This is great, because the end of the countdown triggers the task of doing something. My objective to start monitoring son GPIO from Raspberry Pi for one minute, in a loop, and when the one minute countdown ends, it triggers the task of showing results from the one-minute-long recording/monitoring. Just one question, what is the "args=3" parameter?

Comment: args are the given arguments for functions.
in this example "3" is passed to the countdown function.
-> so its running countdown(3)

Answer (score 0):

Usually python only has a single program flow, so every instruction needs to complete before the next one can get executed.

For your case you need asynchronicity, with e.g. `asyncio.sleep(5)` as a separate task in the same event loop.

```py
import asyncio

async def sleeper():
    print('Holding...')
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print('Doing Work!')

async def work():
    print('Doing work')
    print('while')
    print('the other guy is sleeping')

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(sleeper(), work())

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Thanks Lukas, the thing is that I want to notice one process with the results of the other one. The end on the countdown triggers the execution of the task, I don't want how to communicate processes. I want to keep monitoring a Raspberry Pi GPIO, and after some time, when an user push a button in a GUI, show the results of the recording . This is event-driven programming, and my need is to stop a loop in event-driven programming, so to solve this I have decided to record data during a fix period, and this is why I need to trigger the task of showing results after the countdown in other thread.

Answer (score 0):

The most common and easiest way to implement this would be with a `Timer` object from the `threading` library. It would go as follows:

```
import threading
import time

i = 0
done = False

def show_results():
    print("results from GPIO readings")
    print("=)")
    global done
    done = True   # signal end of while loop

def read_GPIO():
    print("reading GPIO...")


t = threading.Timer(60, show_results)   # task will trigger after 60 seconds
t.start()

# your while loop would go here
read_GPIO()             # do work
while not done:
    print("waiting", i) # doing work while waiting for timer
    time.sleep(1)
    i += 1
    pass
```

Notice that the `time` library is used only for illustrative purposes. You could also **start the timer recursively** to check periodically GPIOs and print results or trigger an event. For more information on the `threading` library or the `Timer` object check [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)